# Log print(window.print()) and email(mailto) events in .aspx pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net, event-handling

Anyone knows how to log print(window.print()) and email(mailto) events for all .aspx pages on the server side with event handlers to be able to store analytics data in the database when they are fired?

Answer (score 0):

You could have an "Analytics.aspx" page on your site. This page would parse incoming posted values, or query string values, and write as appropriate to your database. Eg:

/analytics.aspx?a=email&id=1234

could write an "email" action that occurred on page "1234" to the database.

And then in the page that generates the actions, some javascript to make an ajax call to the analytics.aspx page on whatever action you like, passing through the appropriate variables. Something like the jQuery ajax helpers might help:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Note that "regular" analytics would not be able to be run -- this is assuming you have some sort of custom database. Because your log files might soon contain many links to this "analytics.aspx" page that are meaningless for interpretation without the querystring information.